# Implementing segregated memory storage (malloc) in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to implement my own malloc using a segregated free list (using this textbook as a reference: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/), but I'm not sure how to start.

I have a method, `malloc_init()` that uses `sbrk` to return a slab of memory. Within the context of my assignment, I'm not allowed to ask for more memory after this initial call, and the amount of memory I'm allowed to request is limited by `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` (set by someone else). I am thinking that I will keep an array of pointers, each of which points to a freelist of predetermined size.

How do I set up this array after calling `sbrk`? How do I figure out how many bytes should go into each "bucket" and how the class size of each freelist? In terms of code implementation, how does one set up the array of freelist pointers? Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated! I've looked for example code online but have not found anything satisfying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory allocation theory takes entire chapters or books, but here's some quick ideas to get you started.

You could do something like:

```
char *blobs[10];
```

where blobs[0] points to chunks of 16 bytes, blobs[1] points to chunks of 32 bytes, blobs[2] points to 64 byte chunks, ... upto blobs[9] pointing at 8k chunks.  Then when you get the initial chunk do something like:

```
bsize = 8192;
idx = 9;
memsize = MAX_HEAP_SIZE;
while (idx >= 0) {
    while (memsize > bsize) {
        /* carve a bsize chunk from your initial block */
        /* and insert it onto a singly-linked headed by listblobs[idx]; */
        /* use the first (sizeof(char *)) bytes of each chunk as a next pointer */
    }
    bsize /= 2;
    idx--;
}
```

Then when ever you need to allocate, find the right list and grab a chunk from it.
You'll need to use grab a slightly larger chunk than the request so you have a
place to record which list the chunk came from so you can free it.

You may find making the blobs array more than 10 entries is needed so you can handle larger requests.

If you want to be more sophisticated you can do block dividing when servicing requests.
That is, if somebody requests 33.2K from a 64KB blob, maybe you want to only give then 34KB and divide the remaining space in the 64K blob  into 16K, 8K, 4K, 2K chunks to add to those free lists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, John! One question - I've been trying your implementation and although it makes a lot of sense, I end up with many blocks of very large sizes (i.e. many blocks in bucket 9) and oftentimes not enough memory to fill in the smaller buckets. Would you have suggestions for how to get an even distribution of blocks per bucket? Thanks!

Comment: When the bucket you need is empty, move upwards until you find a non-empty bucket and then divide it.  Lots of dividing strategies, here's an example.   Say you want 128 bytes, but the closest non-empty buckets is the 2048 bytes bucket, so you could divide that in half, put 1 1024 byte chunk on that list, then divide the other 1024 bytes into 2 512 bytes chunks, one you put on the 512 byte list, the other you redivide, putting a 256 byte chunk on that list, then the last 256 bytes you divide into 2 chunks, one goes on the 128 byte list, the other you return.

Comment: When you have the opposite problem (needing a big chunk, but only little chunks are left, you can go through the lists looking (starting at the smallest) looking for chunks whose addresses make them next to each other (for example, 0x0f000020 and 0x000040 on the 32 byte chunk list).  Those 2 chunks you can remove from the smaller list and insert as 1 chunk on the next bigger list (the 64 byte chunk list in my example).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's a "standard" way to do this, but just thinking it through logically: you have a big blob of memory and you want to carve it up into different sized buckets. So first you need to figure out the bucket sizes you're going to support. I'm not a systems programmer, so I can't say what a "good" bucket size is, but I imagine they'll be in some non-consecutive powers of 2 (e.g., 16 bytes, 64 bytes, 512 bytes, etc).

Once you have your bucket sizes, you will need to divide up the memory blob into buckets. The best way is to use a bit of the blob space for a header at the start of each block. The header will contain the size of the block and a flag indicating whether or not it's free.

```
struct header
{
    unsigned short blkSize;
    unsigned char  free;
};
```

In your `init` function you will divide up the blob:

```
void my_init()
{
    // "base" is a pointer to the start of the blob
    void *base = sbrk((intptr_t)MAX_HEAP_SIZE);
    if (!base)
    {
        // something went wrong
        exit(1);
    }

    // carve up the blob into buckets of varying size
    header *hdr = (header*)base;
    for (int i = 0; i < num16Bblocks; i++)
    {
        hdr->blkSize = 16;
        hdr->free    = 1;

        // increment the pointer to the start of the next block's header
        hdr += 16 + sizeof(header);
    }

    // repeat for other sizes
    for (int i = 0; i < num64Bblocks; i++)
    {
        hdr->blkSize = 64;
        hdr->free    = 1;

        // increment the pointer to the start of the next block's header
        hdr += 64 + sizeof(header);
    }

    // etc
}
```

When a user requests some memory, you will walk the blob until you find the smallest bucket that will fit, mark it as no longer free and return a pointer to the start of the bucket:

```
void *my_malloc(size_t allocationSize)
{
    // walk the blocks until we find a free one of the appropriate size
    header *hdr = (header*)base;
    while (hdr <= base + MAX_HEAP_SIZE)
    {
        if (hdr->blkSize >= allocationSize &&
            hdr->free)
        {
            // we found a free block of an appropriate size, so we're going to mark it
            // as not free and return the memory just after the header
            hdr->free = 0;
            return (hdr + sizeof(header));
        }

        // didn't fit or isn't free, go to the next block
        hdr += hdr->blkSize + sizeof(header);
    }

    // did not find any available memory
    return NULL;
}
```

To free (reclaim) some memory, simply mark it as free in the header.

```
void my_free(void *mem)
{
    // back up to the header
    header *hdr = (header*)(mem - sizeof(header));
    // it's free again
    hdr->free = 1;
}
```

This is a very basic implementation and has several drawbacks (e.g., doesn't handle fragmentation, is not very dynamic), but it may give you a good jumping off point.

Comment: Thank you so much, unluddite! I have a followup question about error-checking when you initialize the freelist. If you know how big you want each bucket to be and how many buckets you'll have, is there a way to determine how many blocks of that bucket size you'll have per bucket? Because I could see myself running into a situation in which I'm trying to initialize the segregated free list, but end up not having enough memory allocated by sbrk. Thanks!

Comment: That's tough when you don't know the exact size of memory allocated, because if you want to pre-carve the blob you'd have to do some fancy math to figure out how many of each block size you can have. There may be an alternate way to do this where you don't pre-carve the blob but only allocate blocks on demand--you'll have blocks of varying size next to each other. This is a slightly more dynamic solution in that it will enable you to repurpose larger freed blocks for smaller allocations (with a bit of extra bookkeeping logic).